# Angular directive using ng-class to show hide element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show hide an element inside my directive template on mouseenter.
This is my directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive("addToRoutes",['$http', '$timeout', function($http, $timeout) { 
    return {
        template: '<div><a class="btn btn-default btn-round" ng-click="copy()" ng-mouseenter="showText()" ng-mouseleave="hideText()">\
            <span class="icon icon-spinner icon-spin hidden" ng-class="{hidden : !loading}"></span>\
            <span class="icon icon-plus"   ng-class="{hidden : (loading || copied)}"></span>\
            <span class="icon icon-check hidden" ng-class="{hidden : !copied}"></span>\
            <span class="hidden" ng-class="{hidden : !showFull}">Nach mein Routen Kopieren</span></a></div>\
        ',
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {},
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {   
            var routeId = attrs.route;
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.copied = false;
            $scope.showFull = true;

            $scope.showText = function(){
                $scope.showFull = true;
            }

            $scope.hideText = function(){
                $scope.showFull = false;
            }

            $scope.copy = function(){

            }

        }
    }
}])
```

The showing/hiding works, but only on second iteration, so when i enter, leave and then enter.
I have the feeling it has something to do with the scope variables.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to get this working on the first iteration, set `$scope.showFull` to `false`

### example: http://plnkr.co/edit/g5gWfSOrQDaNbYDQPgyS?p=preview

```
.directive("addToRoutes", function($http, $timeout) {
  return {
    template: '<div><a class="btn btn-default btn-round" ng-click="copy()" ng-mouseenter="showText()" ng-mouseleave="hideText()">\
            <span class="icon icon-spinner icon-spin hidden" ng-class="{hidden : !loading}"></span>\
            <span class="icon icon-plus"   ng-class="{hidden : (loading || copied)}"></span>\
            <span class="icon icon-check hidden" ng-class="{hidden : !copied}"></span>\
            <span class="hidden" ng-class="{hidden : !showFull}">Nach mein Routen Kopieren</span></a></div>\
        ',
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {},
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      var routeId = attrs.route;
      $scope.loading = false;
      $scope.copied = false;
      $scope.showFull = false;

      $scope.showText = function() {
        $scope.showFull = true;
      }

      $scope.hideText = function() {
        $scope.showFull = false;
      }

      $scope.copy = function() {

      }

    }
  }
});
```